# Python функция, SyntaxError

Tags: python, syntax

Пишу функцию которая принимает адрес сайта и возвращает его с https:// в начале.
В итоге я написал вот такую функцию:

```
def normalize_url(site):
    if site[:8] == "http://":
     return site.replace("http://", "https://", 2)
    else site[:8] != "https://":
     return "https://" + site
```

В итоге выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

```
    else site[:8] != "https://":
         ^^^^
SyntaxError: expected ':'
```

Comment: Павел,
E       else site:[:8] != "https://":
E            ^^^^
E   SyntaxError: expected ':'

Comment: Не else, а elif, и без двоеточия

Comment: Павел, всё равно ошибка

Comment: @ysmd если заменили else на elif, та же ошибка на том же месте не может быть. Напишите какая теперь ошибка.

Comment: Мде… тут либо `else` на `elif` менять и оставить двоеточие где оно есть, либо писать `else:`, остаток строки переводить на новую и убрать двоеточие в её конце. А ещё надо брать `site[:7]`, иначе в варианте c http:// будет захватываться первая буква доменного имени.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте вместо else ,elif.

```
def normalize_url(site):
    if site[:8] == "http://":
        return site.replace("http://", "https://", 2)
    elif site[:8] != "https://":
        return "https://" + site
```

Answer (score 0):

Если оставить как у вас, то при вызове сайта с "https://", получим "https://https://"

```
def normalize_url(site):
    if "http://" in site:
        return site.replace("http://", "https://", 2)
    elif "https://" not in site:
        return "https://" + site
    else:
        return site
```